# java fx custom selector on charts

Tags: javafx, stackedbarseries

I have some StackedBarChart containing various series.

```
StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> series1= new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(list1));
StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> series2= new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(list2));
StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> series3= new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(list3));
ObservableList<StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>> barChartData = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList(series1, series2,
                        series3);
        final StackedBarChart<String, Number> chart = new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(
                xAxis, yAxis, barChartData);
```

I'd like to change the default colors of the series.
So I added a custom CSS stylesheet

```
chart.getStylesheets().add("path to the CSS file");
```

In the CSS file I can override the default color with sth like

```
.default-color0 {
    -fx-bar-fill: limegreen;
}
.default-color1 {
    -fx-bar-fill: orange;
}
.default-color2 {
    -fx-bar-fill: tomato;
}
```

This works perfectly but it only replaces the default colors by my colors.
If I change the orders of the series when I add them to the chart, they will switch their colors.

I'd like to be more precise in my CSS with sth like

```
.series1.color {
    -fx-bar-fill: limegreen;
}
.series2.color {
    -fx-bar-fill: orange;
}
.series2.color {
    -fx-bar-fill: tomato;
}
```

and add these custom selectors directly to the series instead of feeding the chart with the CSS stylesheet.
I know there are custom selectors that you can set on Nodes with the `setId(..)` method, but I couldn't manage do it.

I also know about the `lookup` method, but I find it not elegant at all since you have to call it after the chart has been rendered (and therefore you can see the colors blinking very quickly between the original colors and the new ones)

So my question is :
How can I define CSS selectors like

```
.series1.color {
    -fx-bar-fill: limegreen;
}
.series2.color {
    -fx-bar-fill: orange;
}
.series2.color {
    -fx-bar-fill: tomato;
}
```

and apply them programmatically to the chart series I want

```
series1.applySelector(".series1.color");
```

so that even if the series are inserted with a different order in the chart, they still get the color I want

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I added it, you're right it was unclear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the style straight to the component, without editing the CSS:

```
series1.getNode().setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: limegreen;");
series2.getNode().setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: orange;");
series3.getNode().setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: tomato;");
```

Or you can define an id in CSS and set the CSS id for the java compoenten:

**CSS**

```
#clr1 {
    -fx-bar-fill: limegreen;    
}
#clr2 {
    -fx-bar-fill: orange;   
}
#clr3 {
    -fx-bar-fill: tomato;   
}
```

**Java**

```
series1.getNode().setId("clr1");
series2.getNode().setId("clr2");
series3.getNode().setId("clr3");
```

Comment: No I can't. The series don't have setStyle or setId methods. And if I try series1.getNode().  to obtain the setSyle() or setId() methods I get a null pointer exception because the node actually doesn't exist yet (I guess)

Comment: Well you did help me. the getNode() method returns a correct node once the series is added to the chart. So I managed to apply an Id with setId to the series. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, for register I'll edit my answer so.